# Can i jar a class files while skipping error?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

**I want to jar class files while skipping the error.**
The reason is i have a sdk jar file which i decompiled and the classes have alot of errors,however the sdk still works.
I want to edit the decompiled class files with log comments so that i can see which functions are being called and then jar the class files (skip the errors).

currently when i jar a file with error, it jars (eclipse > export jar), however when there is error in the class files, below is the message written in my class files in jar.

**Steps to jar the file:**
Created a java project (Java SE 1.6)  put the classes in the src package,
Export the project as jar file

Please let me know if it is possile

`<Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import android cannot be resolved
    The import android cannot be resolved
    The import sg cannot be resolved
    The import sg cannot be resolved
    The import sg cannot be resolved
    Context cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Context cannot be resolved to a type
    Context cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    CardType cannot be resolved to a variable
    Domain cannot be resolved to a variable
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved
    Log cannot be resolved
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Connector cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved`

Comment: A `.jar` is simply a `.zip` containing the file names. However you probably need to include some library in order to run the application.

Comment: @CommuSoft Hi tried to unzip a jar sdk file and the zip the unzipped contents and change the extension to .jar and put the sdk file in my libs project, however the classes inside the files are not bein recognised sohow is jar same as zip?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in a JAR - source files, class files, images, shopping lists, etc.  Has nothing to do with what can be compiled.  The only thing that distinguishes a JAR from a ZIP is that the JAR may (or may not) have a JAR manifest.

Answer (score 0):

JAR file consist of compiled code (mostly). How can you assembly a jar without compile .java to .class? If you have errors, you must solve them first.

Comment: The reason is that i have jar sdk from developer, it has a lot of errors however it still is in jar file without the above error messages inside them

Comment: It is possible that developer used maven and provided the dependencies on compile ...

Comment: @DeepakTivari - The above error messages are not "inside the JAR file", they occur when you attempt to use the JAR file in a particular context with other classes and JARs and environment settings.  You need to figure out what's not properly configured -- simply omitting stuff from the JAR is not likely to help you at all.